# JUnit which is recommended assertTrue() or assertEquals() for String?

Tags: java, junit

My code is like below

```
@Test
public void testMyMethod(){
    MyClass mc = new MyClass();
    String exeVal="sometext some text";
    String x=mc.exampleMethod();

    // Assertion type 1
    Assert.assertEquals(exeVal,x);
    //Assertion Type 2
    Assert.assertTrue(exeVal.equals(x));
}
```

I want to know which is the best approach.

Comment: It's the same. `assertEquals()` invokes the `equals()` method on given objects. Use whatever you prefer.

Comment: Based solely on readability I would go for assertEquals().

Comment: @BartekMaraszek As `assertEquals` will give you clearer feedback, I'd say it is better to use that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Type 1 is preferred because of the assertion message you will receive when they do not match.

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected: <[foo]> but was: <[bar]>
```

vs

```
java.lang.AssertionError
```

Answer (score 0):

Type 1 is preferred because of the following reasons.

- It gives you a better error message.

ex:- "expected [3] but found [4]" . The second approach will evaluate the condition and will give you a message like "expected [true] but found [false]"  and the user will not get the values evaluated.

- AssertEquals is null safe and assertTrue isn't